# Parse HTML/XML file to find external resources by PHP

Tags: php, html, string, url

I am trying to implement a functionality to parse HTML resource to find all external resources that should be loaded with it (both: absolute and relative). I mean potential images (`<img>` tag), styles (`<link rel>`), scripts (`<script>`) and so on. However the result should be limited only to the resources that are actually loaded so for instance I want to skip `<a>` tag because it requires user action (click on the link).

To do so I thought about using `DOMDocument` class but it throws a lot of potential errors while parsing documents (it's quite strict about `DTD` unfortunately). Do you have some ideas how could I manage it in a sensible manner?

Comment: i wrote a lib that does this, you can check out the source code for refernce if you want: http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/11/01/a-highly-flexible-php-web-crawler-library/

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what I need. I don't need to crawl a site - it's more like finding out how many (and how big) requests there will be generated if I simply write "www.google.com" - for now I already have all the counting and CSS parsing. I've just found that HTML is way more complex in this case.

Comment: I see. You want a headless browser then. PhantomJS is a good one, and super easy to use. They have examples of how to do that on their site. http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Here's the example: http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html

Comment: Yes, I know and I used Phantom a few times - the trick is this specific case I cannot go with any framework...

Comment: it's not a framework, it's a headless browser. you could use cURL. again, there are examples of that in my source code. good luck.

Comment: I know that PhantomJS is not a framework - it was rather a shortcut, sorry. I just meant that I had to write it from a scratch so if frameworks where forbidden then such external tools are also not the case (it was kind of test). Anyway, I decided to go with some crazy regexp to do so... :)